# Repeat HTML code with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to have html/javascript code to repeat html-code?
Basically, I need to use plain javascript and at the same time I need to build html elements in a for loop.
So in html I can have:

```
<div>col1</div>
<div>col2></div>
<div>col3</div>
```

The problem is that there can be several sets of the above html code.
What I'm doing now is to write html inside the javascript code.
I would like to make it cleaner and have the html structure where it belongs, which is in the html-page.

Comment: You should consider a template engine

Comment: Template engine like Handlebars.js

Comment: Well I now that it would solve the problem. Thing is that Im in a project where I need to use plain javascript.

Comment: @oderfla a template engine is plain javascript :) I guess what you mean is that you can't use an external library?

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad. I meant I cannot use external libraries.

Comment: There is this post that will help you (suggests using innerHTML): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422095/insert-html-as-a-string-without-jquery

Answer (score 5):

You can try something along these lines:

```
for(i = 0;i<howeverManyYouNeed;i++)
{
    document.getElementById("parentId").innerHTML += "<div>col"+i+"</div>";
}
```

Comment: He says he is already doing this currently. But he wants to put it in html.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you write your own minimal templating library if you're using ES-6 templates. See this blogpost on how to do that: http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/template-strings-html.html