# Making an html component multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

If I wanted to use a component 20 times on my page (Eg. The following, which is a box with 4 range sliders), is there a way to do this without writing this code 20 times? Is there something similar to the react component in html? Thank you!

```
<div class = "slidecontainer" id = sliders>
<br>
<label for = "Slider A"><input type = "range" min = "0" max = "100" value = "0" class = "slider" id = "slider_A"> &nbsp; <span id = "slider-value-A"></span></label><br>
<label><input type = "range" min = "0" max = "100" value = "0" class = "slider" id = "slider_B"> &nbsp; <span id = "slider-value-B"></span> &nbsp; </label><br>
<label><input type = "range" min = "0" max = "100" value = "0" class = "slider" id = "slider_C"> &nbsp; <span id = "slider-value-C"></span> &nbsp; </label><br>
<label><input type = "range" min = "0" max = "100" value = "0" class = "slider" id = "slider_D"> &nbsp; <span id = "slider-value-D"></span> &nbsp; </label>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Plain HTML does not have that functionality. You will have to use some framework (like React or Vue) to do that.

Comment: Then do I have no other choice but to write it multiple times if I am only using html? Would it be better if I used javascript to do it instead?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228196/repeat-html-code-with-plain-javascript) is an answer with just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, You can write plain JavaScript in a common.js file and set content by ID or Class on multiple pages/places.