# How to add div inside the dom element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs

When I am debugging one of my list I am using something like this.

```
this.list.dom;
```

Here What I am getting, some div which I is something like that.

`this.list.dom.outerHTML`

```
<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="ext-gen389" style="position: absolute; z-index: 12005; visibility: visible; left: 315px; top: 175px; width: 228px; height: 22px; font-size: 11px;">
    <div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen390" style="width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 22px;">
        <div class="loading-indicator">Searching, please wait...</div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Now I want to add some div in side the `this.list.dom`. This should bve like this.

`this.list.dom.outerHTML`

```
'<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="ext-gen389" style="position: absolute; z-index: 12005; visibility: visible; left: 315px; top: 175px; width: 228px; height: 22px; font-size: 11px;">
    <div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen390" style="width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 22px;">
        <div class="loading-indicator">Searching, please wait...</div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: solid 3px #000; padding: 2px;">Message</div>'

Can anyone suggest me how to add this. I am new in client side.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML as a String, without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422095/insert-html-as-a-string-without-jquery)

Comment: Check this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622465/creating-a-div-element-inside-a-div-element-in-javascript

Comment: @Harshal ID is generating dynamically. It will change component to component.

Comment: @shankysingh Are you trying to show some loading on Combobox while data is being fetched using ExtJS ?

Comment: Yes, Trying to doing the same, My extJs is 3 so can not use `listconfig`

Answer (score 0):

You can use set existing `HTML` string at   `<template>` element, use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` with `"beforeend"` as first parameter and `HTML` string as second parameter

```js
let dom = `<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="ext-gen389" style="position: absolute; z-index: 12005; visibility: visible; left: 315px; top: 175px; width: 228px; height: 22px; font-size: 11px;"><div style="border: solid 3px #000; padding: 2px;">Message</div>
    <div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen390" style="width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 22px;">
        <div class="loading-indicator">Searching, please wait...</div>
    </div>
</div>`;

let template = document.createElement("template");

template.innerHTML = dom;

template.content.firstElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div style="border: solid 3px #000; padding: 2px;">Message</div>`);

document.body.innerHTML += template.innerHTML;
```

Comment: `template.content.firstElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML` This is throwing the error by saying ` Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null`.

Comment: Error is thrown at stacksnippets?

Comment: No, But I am trying in project there it throwing error.

Comment: Given description of requirement at original Question no error should be thrown. `this.list.dom.outerHTML` is a string. The string is set at `.innerHTML` of a `<template>` element. An `HTML` string `<div style="border: solid 3px #000; padding: 2px;">Message</div>` is inserted before the end of the `.firstElementChild` of `template.content`. You can get the `HTML` content of the `template` element using `.innerHTML`

Comment: After executing `template.innerHTML = dom;` line when I am checking `template.outerHTML` then I am getting this. `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`

Comment: @shankysingh Not sure how that is possible. Why do you try to get `.outerHTML` of `<template>` element? That is not the property that is accessed at stacksnippets.  Can you reproduce what you are describing at stacksnippets or plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: ok, One loast question, Can Not I create a div and `appand` that div to the main div which have id `id="ext-gen389"`

Comment: Yes, if that is what you want to do